# For a Lebesgue measurable $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, what does $m^*(E)=\infty$ imply?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was studying Royden and Fitzpatrick's book on Real Analysis. At one instance in their proof about the outer approximations by open sets, they said that: if $E$ is a measurable set such that  $m^*(E)=\infty$ (where $m^*$ is the outer measure set function), then there exists a countable collection $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of pairwise disjoint measurable sets with finite measure such that $E= \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$. Why is this true?

Edit: This is how it was worded in the book:

"...Now consider the case that $m^*(E)=\infty$. Then $E$ may be expressed as the disjoint union of a countable collection $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of measurable sets, each of which has finite outer measure..."

Last edit: I'm just going to emphasize here that the outer measure of $E$ is infinite, $m^*(E)=\infty$, and I am not exactly sure what kinds of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ would give infinite outer measure. The most obvious thing that comes to my mind are infinite rays, that is, intervals of the form $(a,+ \infty)$ or $(- \infty,a)$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Which obviously we can just cover by disjoint open intervals (which are measurable, and have finite outer measure). But there might be any **other** forms of $E$ that might give infinite outer measure.

Comment: Are we talking about measurable subsets of the real numbers or something? This is usually not true in general. The property needed is called $\sigma$-finiteness.

Comment: Yes, we are talking about measurable subsets on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The question actually was, if you're talking about $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I might have worded it awkwardly, $\mathbb{R}^n$ never entered the picture.

Comment: Do we have any condition on the measure? Absolute continuity? Lebesgue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to get at. But by $E$ being measurable, I mean Lebesgue measurable. I hope that helps.